# How I can run Netlogo platform agent based modeling in Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netlogo

I want to simulate my model in multi-agent platform (Netlogo) and will run it on a Docker container, can you give me a solution for this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run `Netlogo` in a docker container.

There are lot of images out there on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/).

https://hub.docker.com/r/comses/netlogo

https://hub.docker.com/r/similitude/netlogo-docker

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank your @mchawre for your answers

Comment: Great! Nice to hear that.